# COM client side security for signed dlls

Tags: c++, com

Is there a way to tell COM to load only signed dlls in my process else fail?

What if someone overwrites the OBJID entries and re-route to his dll

Comment: Wrong side of the airtight hatchway.  An attacker needs admin privileges to modify CLSID registration.  He won't do this the hard way when he has that right.

Comment: I agree that the attacker has the same privilege as the target process and need not do this.  But that doesn't mean we can always allow an unknown dll to load into my process. What if i am writing a browser, and some dll can indeed read my memory and read the passwords.

Comment: Short answer is no. Some dll can only read your memory if some user with proper rights has allowed it to do so, directly or indirectly.